# Couldn't match expected type in haskell

Tags: haskell

```hs
    data NumberSystem = NumberSystem_ NumberSystemType deriving(Show,Eq,Read)
    data NumberSystemType = Decimal | Binary | Hex | Ocatl deriving(Show,Eq,Read)
    data Constant = Number Int deriving(Show,Eq,Read)
    
    data Number1 = NumberSystem Constant
    data Number2 = NumberSystemType Constant
    
    value1 = (NumberSystem_ Binary) (Number 10010)
    value2 = (Binary) (Number 101)
```

Getting Error for both variables value1 and value2.

```
NumberSystem.hs:20:10: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Constant -> t’
                  with actual type ‘NumberSystem’
    • The function ‘NumberSystem_’ is applied to two arguments,
      but its type ‘NumberSystemType -> NumberSystem’ has only one
      In the expression: (NumberSystem_ Binary) (Number 10010)
      In an equation for ‘value1’:
          value1 = (NumberSystem_ Binary) (Number 10010)
    • Relevant bindings include
        value1 :: t (bound at NumberSystem.hs:20:1)
   |
20 | value1 = (NumberSystem_ Binary) (Number 10010)
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

NumberSystem.hs:22:10: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Constant -> t’
                  with actual type ‘NumberSystemType’
    • The function ‘Binary’ is applied to one argument,
      but its type ‘NumberSystemType’ has none
      In the expression: (Binary) (Number 101)
      In an equation for ‘value2’: value2 = (Binary) (Number 101)
    • Relevant bindings include
        value2 :: t (bound at NumberSystem.hs:22:1)
   |
22 | value2 = (Binary) (Number 101)
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
Prelude>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `(Binary) (Number 101)` is interpreted as *calling* the `Binary` constructor with 1 argument, `Number 101`, but `Binary` doesn’t have any fields. That’s why the error message reads:

```
    • The function ‘Binary’ is applied to one argument,
      but its type ‘NumberSystemType’ has none
```

If you want `Number1` and `Number2` to denote a *pair* of a number system type and a number, you’re missing a constructor name in their definitions:

```
data Number1 = Number1 NumberSystem Constant
data Number2 = Number2 NumberSystemType Constant

value1 :: Number1
value1 = Number1 (NumberSystem_ Binary) (Number 10010)

value2 :: Number2
value2 = Number2 Binary (Number 101)
```

The `NumberSystem` type is redundant, though, since it only contains a single field of type `NumberSystemType`, so you can consolidate these two definitions into a single type, and the same for `Number1` and `Number2`. For consistency, I’ll follow the conventional Haskell style of naming the *data* constructor the same as the *type* constructor for each type.

```
-- A ‘NumberSystemType’ is one of the following 4 constructors.
data NumberSystemType = Decimal | Binary | Hex | Octal
  deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

-- ‘Constant’ has 1 constructor, also named ‘Constant’,
-- with 1 field of type ‘Int’. (So ‘newtype’ would also work.)
data Constant = Constant Int
  deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

-- A ‘Number’ has 2 fields, of type ‘NumberSystemType’ and ‘Constant’.
data Number = Number NumberSystemType Constant
  deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

value1, value2 :: Number
value1 = Number Binary (Constant 10010)
value2 = Number Binary (Constant 101)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data NumberSystem = NumberSystem_ NumberSystemType Constant deriving(Show,Eq,Read)
```

```
value2 = NumberSystem_ Binary (Number 101)
```